# Common Properties missing in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm following page 15 of this: http://www.yetanotherquant.com/QuantLib/book/BookQuantLib.pdf

In figure 1.4, when I rightclick on DateToy, I should be able to see Common Properties and Configuration Properties. However, I only see Configuration Properties in the VS2015 that I'm using

anyone know why?

Comment: That was pretty broken in previous versions, they fixed it.

Comment: I'm using the newest version of Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to add references to your project?
Common Properties section has been moved to Reference Manager.
In solution explorer, right click on "References" node in your project, and choose your references there.
FYI:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab.aspx